# For what values of $ a, b$ does the equation have real roots?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

> For what values of $a,b$ does the equation
>   $${ x }^{ 2 }+2\left( 1+a \right) x+\left( 3{ a }^{ 2 }+4ab+4{ b }^{ 2 }+2 \right) = 0$$
>   have real roots?

For it to have real roots, the discriminant has to be $>0$, correct? (Or equal to, I suppose, since the question didn't specify distinct or not) So I tried using the values, which gave me ${ \left( 2+2a \right)  }^{ 2 }-4\left( 3{ a }^{ 2 }+4ab+4{ b }^{ 2 } +2\right) $ but I'm not sure where to go after that.

Comment: You are correct that the discriminant has to be greater than zero, in order to have two real roots (assuming $a,b$ are real coefficients).  You would get a double real root if the discriminant was exactly zero.

Answer (score 7):

You have the right idea.
You just need to continue
expanding that expression.

From
$x^2 + 2(1+a)x + (3a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2 + 2) = 0
$,
the discriminant is
(ignoring the factor of 2
since we are concerned
only about the sign)

$\begin{array}\\
d
&=(1+a)^2-(3a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2 + 2)\\
&=a^2+2a+1-(3a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2 + 2)\\
&=-2a^2+2a-1-4ab-4b^2\\
&=-a^2+2a-1-a^2-4ab-4b^2
\quad\text{This is the key step}\\
&=-(a-1)^2-(2b+a)^2\\
\end{array}
$

So,
in the miraculous way of many homework problems,
this is the negative
of a sum of two squares.

So $d \le 0$
and,
for $d = 0$,
we must have
$a=1$ and
$2b+a=0$,
which means
$b = -1/2$.

For any other values of
$a$ and $b$,
the discriminant is negative,
and so there are no real roots.

For these values of $a$ and $b$,
there is a repeated root.

Comment: In general I don´t agree, that ignoring the factor 2 is right here. Could you give me more explanation why it is allowed here.

Comment: Could you explain why we can ignore the factor of 2? Also, after that if it's correct, that means there are NO values of a,b in which the equation has 2 real roots right? Well, the question didn't specify distinct though, so the answer must be the repeated root.

Comment: You are searching for when $\Delta\ge0$, but you have $\Delta\ge0\iff k\Delta\ge0$ where $k$ is positive

Comment: $b^2-4ac = 4((b/2)^2 - ac)$, so the sign of $b^2-4ac$, which is what we are interested in, is the same as the sign of $(b/2)^2-ac$.

Comment: Sorry Elliot, can you elaborate?

Comment: Also marty, if I were to keep the 2 in, could I still expand and factor to get similar results?

Comment: yes,,,you;d just get 2 times each term in the factorization and simplification.

Comment: So we want the discriminant to be greater than or equal to zero, so in general $b^2-4ac\ge 0$. But we can multiply both sides by any positive number and preserve the inequality: $b^2-4ac\ge 0 \iff k\cdot(b^2-4ac)\ge k\cdot 0=0$

Comment: he ignored the factor of $2$ because after that would give him $4$ and he just factored with $4$ so it doesn't really matter for finding the sign

Comment: @ElliotG But only b was multiplied by 0.5-not c.

Comment: As i said, you can multiply by and positive number. If the discriminant is greater or equal to zero, then half of it is also greater or equal to zero

Comment: Okay, I've understood it now, thanks all.

Comment: @ElliotG And therefore the solution of John Hughes is wrong ?

Comment: im not really sure what he is saying

Comment: @ElliotG Thanks for the answers. I understand now. I haven´t considered the 4 in $b^2-4ac$. Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is easy to complete the square $$(x+1+a)^2+3a^2+4ab+4b^2+2-(1+a)^2=0$$ so that $$(x+1+a)^2=-2a^2+2a-1-4b^2-4ab=-(a-1)^2-(2b+a)^2$$

This step involves simply completing the square for $4b^2+4ab=(2b+a)^2-a^2$ and seeing what is left.

The left-hand side is non-negative, the right-hand side non-positive, so equality is only possible if both are zero.

Note: this is wholly equivalent to working with the discriminant, but saves a factor of $4$ and does not require remembering a formula.